# Mock instance created from class stored in variable

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have the following code:

```py
class Messenger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Class Type of what messages will be created as.
        message_class = Message

    def publish(self, body):
        # Instantiate object of type stored in `message_class`
        message = message_class(body)
        message.publish()
```

I want to assert that the `Message.publish()` method is called. How do I achieve this?

I've already tried the following ways:

1. Assign `message_class` to `Mock` or `Mock()`. If I debug what `message_class(body)` returns, it is a Mock, but I don't seem to be able to get the instance and assert it (because the Mock I assign in my test is not the instance used, it is the Type).
2. Patch `Message` class with decorator. Whenever I do this it seems like it does not catch it. When I debug what `message_class(body)` returns its of `Message` type, not Mock.
3. Try to mock the `__init__` method of `message_class` in hopes that I can set the instance that is returned whenever the code tries to Instantiate the message. Does not work, throws errors because the `__init__` method is not suppose to have a return value.

Answer (score 0):

If you were storing the actual instance, I'd say you could do something like `messenger.message.publish.assert_called_once`, but since `message_class` is being stored, it makes it slightly trickier. Given that, you can pull the `return_value` from the mocked `class` and check the call that way. Here's how I did it:

Messenger. Note the slight modification to assign `message_class` to self. I'm assuming you meant to do that, otherwise it wouldn't work without some global funkiness:

```
'''messenger.py'''
class Message(object):
    def __init__(self, body):
        self.body = body

    def publish(self):
        print('message published: {}'.format(self.body))


class Messenger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Class Type of what messages will be created as.
        self.message_class = Message

    def publish(self, body):
        # Instantiate object of type stored in `message_class`
        message = self.message_class(body)
        message.publish()
```

Test:

```
'''test_messenger.py'''    
from unittest import mock, TestCase

from messenger import Messenger

class TestMessenger(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('messenger.Message')
    def test_publish(self, mock_message):
        messenger = Messenger()
        messenger.publish('test body')
        # .return_value gives the mock instance, from there you can make your assertions
        mock_message.return_value.publish.assert_called_once()
```